# How to read a single file in Heroku via bash

Tags: git, bash, heroku

I'm trying to read a file in Heroku because it's an old website where Git got corrupted and I no longer have the files for it. I have rolled back to its version to to read from it and I've gotten to the bash folder where it is using

```
heroku run bash
ls app/views/
```

How can I read my file from here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to clone the repo from Heroku and get the files from Git locally.

```
git clone git@heroku.com:<your app>.git

git co <revision>
```

You should then be able to access your files.

Comment: I got `Permission denied (publickey)` but then I tried again with `git clone https://git.heroku.com/<yourapp>.git` and it worked.

Answer (score 34):

When you are using bash you can just cat the file

`heroku run bash -a my-app`

and then :

`ls app/views/
cat my_super_file`

Comment: After removing a file using this bash method, do I need to do something to have the change take place? I deleted a folder with images . I confirm that by doing ls and there is now directory. should you git push or heroku restart or something like that. I still see the images. Edit I typed `exit`. and did `heroku run bash -a my-app` and now I see that the directory is still there after I thought I deleted it.

Comment: This is how heroku works, it will protect your application. from being hacked. You can imagine that when you type heroku run bash -a my-app, heroku creates a new server, configure it with your application, your addons, your database and connect you to it. You will not change the files on any of your running dynos. If you want to remove a folder, you need to push a new version of your application. You can find more informations here :https://12factor.net/